# Angular 12 - 'healcode-widget' is not a known element

Tags: angular

I am migrating from Angular 1 to Angular 12. I need to integrate a 3rd party module from mindbody and all I had to do in Angular 1 was include the JS file in the index.html file, as below:

```
<script src="https://widgets.mindbodyonline.com/javascripts/healcode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After that, I can just use it - see below:

```
<healcode-widget data-type="schedules" data-widget-partner="object" data-widget-id="0412695814c0" data-widget-version="1"></healcode-widget>
```

Pretty straightforward stuff.

I do the same in Angular 12 and I am getting the below error message:

```
Build at: 2021-08-04T10:40:55.936Z - Hash: d638a8e9e63fb049170b - Time: 420ms

Error: src/app/class/weekly/weekly.component.html:14:17 - error NG8001: 'healcode-widget' is not a known element:
1. If 'healcode-widget' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'healcode-widget' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

What is it that I have to do in order to be able to use the third party JS file? It seems too simple a problem but I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
//Same file
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
```

That did the trick